# Sleeping barber problem in Erlang

Tags: beginner, random, simulation, erlang

I'm learning Erlang. It's my first time with a non-imperative programming language.

I've written a code and I want some thoughts about it:

- Is my logic easy to understand?
- Is my code idiomatic?
- Is my code well organized?
- Is my code using Erlang features correctly?

My goal here is improve readability and functional-thinking. I'm not concerned about performance.

```
-module(sb).
-export([start/0, barberShop/3, clientGenerator/2, barber/2]).
-define(MAX_BARBERS, 1).
-define(MAX_SITS, 5).

start() ->
  BarberShopPID = spawn(sb, barberShop, [[], 0, yes]),
  spawn(sb, clientGenerator, [BarberShopPID, 10]).

clientGenerator(BarberShopPID, ClientsToGenerate) ->
  case ClientsToGenerate of
    0 ->
      BarberShopPID ! clientGeneratorIsDone;
    _ ->
      timer:sleep(random(1000, 6000)),
      Hair = random(100, 600),
      BarberShopPID ! {client, Hair},
      clientGenerator(BarberShopPID, ClientsToGenerate-1)
  end.

barberShop(Clients, Barbers, IsCGRunning) ->
  receive
    {client, Hair} ->
      case length(Clients) of
        ?MAX_SITS ->
          write("A client entered, but there are no available sits."),
          barberShop(Clients, Barbers, IsCGRunning);
        _ ->
          write("A client entered and found a available sit."),
          {NewC, NewB} = tryAttend([Hair | Clients], Barbers, self()),
          barberShop(NewC, NewB, IsCGRunning)
      end;
    barberIsDone ->
      {NewC, NewB} = tryAttend(Clients, Barbers-1, self()),
      case shouldContinue(NewC, NewB, IsCGRunning) of
        yes ->
          barberShop(NewC, NewB, IsCGRunning);
        no ->
          write("Bye from the glorious barber shop.")
      end;
    clientGeneratorIsDone ->
      case shouldContinue(Clients, Barbers, no) of
        yes ->
          {NewC, NewB} = tryAttend(Clients, Barbers, self()),
            barberShop(NewC, NewB, no);
        no ->
          write("Bye from the glorious barber shop.")
      end
  end.

barber(Hair, BarberShopPID) ->
  write("Barber started his job."),
  timer:sleep(Hair * 10),
  write("Barber has done his job."),
  BarberShopPID ! barberIsDone.

tryAttend(Clients, ?MAX_BARBERS, _) ->
  {Clients, ?MAX_BARBERS};
tryAttend([], Barbers, _) ->
  {[], Barbers};
tryAttend(Clients, Barbers, BarberShopPID) ->
  [First | Rest] = Clients,
  spawn(sb, barber, [First, BarberShopPID]),
  {Rest, Barbers+1}.

shouldContinue([], 0, no) ->
  no;
shouldContinue(_, _, _) ->
  yes.

random(Min, Max) ->
  random:uniform(Max-Min+1)+Min.

write(Message) ->
  io:format(Message ++ "~n", []).
```

Comment: I don't know this language at all and I think I can mostly figure out what is happening - so that's good. Good question +1

Comment: No one to help me. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall it looks good, I would just have some minor comments. In any case please have a look at the [official Ericsson guidance](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml).

1. Use macro `?MODULE` instead of repeating `sb`.
2. In Erlang function names are `usually_with_underscores` rather than `camelCasing`. There are some exceptions, even in OTP applications, but in general underscores help to distinguish functions from variable names, which are usually `CamelCased`. The same holds for atom names.
3. I would usually put a code like this: `[First | Rest] = Clients` directly to the function argument to make it shorter, e.g.: `tryAttend([First | Rest] = Clients, Barbers, BarberShopPID) ->`
4. `NewC` and `NewB` aren't very descriptive. I would rather use `NClients` if `NewClients` are too long for you.
5. When accessing the head and tail of a list the names of variables are usually `H` and `T`, unless you want a specific name for the head, in which case the tail is just `T` or `Tail`, e.g. `[H|T] = Clients` or `[First|T] = Clients`. It's a convention which you will notice when reading someone else's code.
6. When spawning process with a function that doesn't need to be exported for its own sake try to use `fun`, e.g.: `spawn(fun() -> barber(First, BarberShopPID) end)`. It's better to not expose functions that are not meant to be called from outside. And if you do have to export a function like that, then it's better to put it into a separate `export` with an additional comment, e.g. `%% Internal API`.
7. Didn't you want to write `MAX_SEATS` rather than `MAX_SITS`? :)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! And yes, it's "seats" , my bad :)